# Detect if node receives stdin

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm interested in determining if my node script is being called with data being streamed into it or not. That is, I want to differentiate between these two cases

```bash
$ node index.js
$ ls | node index.js
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`process.stdin.isTTY`](https://nodejs.org/api/tty.html#readstreamistty) will be falsy (`undefined`) when you have data piped to stdin and `true` when you don't:

```bash
$ node -e "console.log(process.stdin.isTTY)"
true
$ ls | node -e "console.log(process.stdin.isTTY)"
undefined
```

See docs: https://nodejs.org/api/tty.html

Comment: To be clear this true only if your execution environment has a TTY. For example:
`$ node -e "console.log({hasTTY: process.stdin.isTTY}); process.exit(1)"` gives `{ hasTTY: true }` as expected. Likewise `$ echo "" | node -e "console.log({hasTTY: process.stdin.isTTY}); process.exit(1)"` gives `{ hasTTY: undefined }` as expected. However `$ npx nodemon --exec 'node -e "console.log({hasTTY: process.stdin.isTTY}); process.exit(1)"'` results in `{ hasTTY: undefined }` which is not. Tested in NodeJS 18.